# Efecto de cambio de color de transparente de un Toolbar

Tags: android

Llevo intentando conseguir el efecto de cambiar el color de un toolbar a medida que se desplaza, inicialmente lo tengo en transparente y ni bien comienza a desplazar hacia abajo este que  cambie de color poco a poco hasta coseguir su color establecido.
seria maso menos asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo intente con el atributo app:contentScrim="@color/colorAccent" pero no sale exactamente como quisiera, muchas Gracias de antemano.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_appbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarMore"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero de todo, tienes que saber cómo abordad tu problema separandolo en pequeños pasos. Esto no te lo digo a malas, simplemente es un buen consejo que me hubiese gustado que me lo dieran a mi en su momento, por eso te voy a poner un ejemplo de cómo abordar este problema.

Si como expones, necesitas que cuando el usuario se desplace hacia abajo en la activity, la toolbar, desaparezca y que ocurra lo contrario cuando el usuario suba, tienes que realizar los siguientes pasos:

1. Ver como poder detectar el movimiento de la pantalla.
2. Saber como enlazar el efecto en la `Toolbar`.

Si los separas así sera más fácil encontrar un solución, porque por desgracia Android no tiene función ni solución para todo.

**DETECTAR EL MOVIMIENTO**

Como tienes implementado un `RecyclerView` viene muy bien esta solución, porque así a este elemento le podemos añadir un escuchador para que detecte el desplazamiento, por ejemplo:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){
        if (dy > 0){ 
            // Se detecta un desplazamiento hacia abajo 
        } else if (dy == 0) { 
            // Se detecta que esta arriba del todo                
    }
});
```

Te dejo en este enlace la [guía](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html?hl=es) de `Android Developer` sobre lo anterior.

**CREAR EL EFECTO EN LA TOOLBAR**

Luego de saber cuando se mueve o no, solamente tendremos que añadir al ejemplo anterior el efecto de desaparecer. Esto puedes realizarlo con [AlphaAnimation(float fromAlpha, float toAlpha)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html?hl=es):

Para hacer aparecer la `Toolbar`:

```
AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(1000); // Durará un segundo
toolbar.startAnimation(animation);
```

Para hacerla desaparecer:

```
AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
animation.setDuration(1000); // Durará un segundo
toolbar.startAnimation(animation);
```

Espero que haya quedado claro, si no coméntame e intentare ayudarte. De todas formas tengo que avisarte de que no he conseguido probar el código dado que tengo a Android Studio actualizándose. En cualquier cosa, avísame por favor.

¡¡Suerte!!

Comment: Hola @Vicky gracias si funciona como me lo explicaste y también gracias por el consejo de dividir el problema.

Answer (score -1):

Los Toolbars en algunas ocaciones pueden ser tratados como una vista, prueba :

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```